# Trying to figure out the logic of this current time and date code

Tags: javascript

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
       console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
        var hour = today.getHours();
        var minute = today.getMinutes();
        var second = today.getSeconds();
        var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
        hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;

if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ') 
{    
if (minute===0 && second===0)
{  
hour=12;
prepand=' Noon';
}  
else
{  
hour=12;
prepand=' PM';
}  
}

if (hour===0 && prepand===' AM ') 
{    
if (minute===0 && second===0)
{  
hour=12;
prepand=' Midnight';
}  
else
{  
hour=12;
prepand=' AM';
}  
}  


console.log("Current Time : "+hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
```

I'm trying to figure out how does the if statement work in this code. It doesn't make any sense to me. please see below comments. for the different time period why the hour=12 for all? I think  am totally lost in this part.

```
if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ')    
{    
if (minute===0 && second===0)
{  
hour=12;  //when it is noon, the hour will be 12, and prepand will be "pm"...but why here it is still 12? 
prepand=' Noon';
}  
else
{  
hour=12;
prepand=' PM';
}  
}


if (hour===0 && prepand===' AM ') 
{    
if (minute===0 && second===0)
{  
hour=12;    //isn't when it is 24 for midnight? why 12 again? 
prepand=' Midnight';
}  
else
{  
hour=12;    //and why it is still 12 for else? 
prepand=' AM';
}  
}
```

Comment: It looks like this will return `11:59:59 PM`, `12:00:00 Midnight`, and `12:00:01 AM`. The hour could be set outside the check to change prepend, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is determining if it is noon or midnight by formatting the date/time from [24-hour clock format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) (used by most of the world, and by JavaScript) to [12-hour clock format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) (used in the United States).

Here is a simplified version of your code, with some notes:

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();
var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
var hour = today.getHours(); 
var minute = today.getMinutes();
var second = today.getSeconds();
var prepand = (hour >= 12) ? " PM " : " AM ";

// Convert from 24-hour time to 12-hour time
hour = (hour >= 12) ? hour - 12 : hour;

if (hour === 0 && minute === 0 && second === 0) {
  // It is either midnight or noon on a 12 hour clock
  // Both midnight and noon on a 12-hour clock is 12:00:00
  hour = 12;

  if(prepand === ' PM ') {
      // It is 12:00:00 on a 12-hour and a 24-hour clock
      prepand = ' Noon';
  } else { // prepand = AM
      // It is 12:00:00 on a 12-hour clock and 00:00:00 on a 24-hour clock
      prepand = ' Midnight';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the script is trying to show `Midnight` and `Noon` only if the time is exactly midnight or noon, meaning minutes and seconds both equal 0. The logic is overly complex and could be boiled down to something much more readable and concise such as:

```
  if (hour === 0) {
    hour = 12;

    if (minute === 0 && second === 0)
      prepend = prepend === ' AM ' ? ' Midnight ' : ' Noon ';
  }
```

Here is a code snippet. Notice `Midnight` and `Noon` only show up when there are no minutes or seconds.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var day = date.getDay(),
    daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday ", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    hour = date.getHours() % 12,
    minute = date.getMinutes(),
    second = date.getSeconds(),
    prepend = hour === date.getHours() ? ' AM ' : ' PM ';

  if (hour === 0) {
    hour = 12;

    if (minute === 0 && second === 0)
      prepend = prepend === ' AM ' ? ' Midnight ' : ' Noon ';
  }

  return daylist[day] + ' ' + hour + ':' + ('00' + minute).substr(-2) + ':' + ('00' + second).substr(-2) + prepend
}

/// Setup for demo
var _input = document.getElementById('inp'),
    _btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
    _output = document.getElementById('out');

_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var msg = 'Not a valid date';
  
  if (!isNaN(Date.parse(_input.value)))
    msg = formatDate(new Date(_input.value));
  
  _output.innerText = msg;
})
```

```html
<input id='inp' value='2015/01/01 00:00:00' />
<button type='button' id='btn'>Go</button>
<div id='out'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make **any sense** :

```
if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ')
```

`prepand` is already defined a bit earlier as:

```
var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
```

so logically `prepand` is already `" PM "` if `hour >= 12` and logically `" AM "` if `hour < 12`

and the `if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ')` will never trigger since it cannot be at the same time `hour` 0 and `prepand` " PM " since JS's method `.getHours()` returns values from 0-23

---

Also, make your life easier and avoid trickeries like `" AM "` and `" AM"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDay();
  var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
  var hour = today.getHours();
  var minute = today.getMinutes();
  var second = today.getSeconds();
  var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
  hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;
  if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ') 
  { 
  if (minute===0 && second===0)
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' Noon';
  } 
  else
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' PM';
  } 
  } 
  if (hour===0 && prepand===' AM ') 
  { 
  if (minute===0 && second===0)
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' Midnight';
  } 
  else
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' AM';
  } 
  } 
console.log("Current Time : "+hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).